# Python script A has inputs and outputs. Script B has a class structure and functions. Pythonic solution for A to call on B using A variables?

Tags: python, list, variables, global-variables

I have many unique "A" scripts that all use the same class and function structures in script "B".

**Ideal Python Script A**

```
import idealB

biglist = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta']
uniquelist1 = ['beta', 'delta']
uniquelist2 = ['alpha', 'gamma']

master(input):
     idealB.classfromB.functionfromB(input)

for i in biglist:
     master(i)

export data
```

**Ideal Python Script B**

```
class classfromB:
     def __init__(self, data1, data2):
          self.data1 = data1
          self.data2 = data2

     def functionfromB(input):
          if input in uniquelist1:
                do stuff
          elif input in uniquelist2:
                do different stuff
```

When I try to run something like this, I get the following:

```
NameError: name 'uniquelist1' is not defined
```

Script A calls on script B correctly, but script B doesn't have a defined "uniquelist1" so it throws a name error. How do I get script A to call on a class and function from script B to work with defined variables in script A?

Script B is where tweaking and editing of functions occurs but there are several different versions of Script A, so I would love to be able to just edit script B and call on it. My current, yet tedious, solution is to copy and paste all of B into each A script and it runs well even though it isn't elegant. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

redefine your functions to take `uniquelist1` as an input. So in script B, instead of
`def functionfromB(input):` do `def functionfromB(input, uniquelist1):` and in script A replace `idealB.classfromB.functionfromB(input)` with `idealB.classfromB.functionfromB(input, uniquelist1)`

Comment: This worked great, but it revealed the next problem. The data is not returning from script B. Everything is working, but the data is not being returned to script A. The "do stuff" creates a listofobjects that are then repackaged with A-specific information. I tried: return listofobjects but received the following ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 10, got 0). How and where would you export the Script B listofobjects? Thank you!